# How do i get Physical memory of my computer using WMI query in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi

Is there a way to get available memory using WMI query in C# code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code generated with [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8572):

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WMISample
{
    public class MyWMIQuery
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
                    new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", 
                    "SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"); 

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("Win32_ComputerSystem instance");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("TotalPhysicalMemory: {0}", queryObj["TotalPhysicalMemory"]);
                }
            }
            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For more accurate total physical memory use "Capacity" property of  "Win32_PhysicalMemory" class. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394102(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Actually, I wanted to add a reference to where it mentions this. It's on that link and down the page under TotalPhysicalMemory. But a link to Win32_PhysicalMemory wouldn't hurt either. :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394347(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Can I read from Hyper-V?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/getram_vbs.txt